# how can I use connect_error in an if condition?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was studying an example from mysqli connection and I am confused!
the method connect_error returns string or null.so how can we use it in an if condition when is doesn't return true or false?
example code:

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="example";
$conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("connection is failed".$conn->connect_error);
      }
        ?>
```

Comment: The condition doesn't have to be true or false. null is considered to be false, while any non-empty string is considered to be true.

Comment: `null` is a "falsy" value and a non empty string is a "truthy" value

Comment: Anything inside an `if` condition will be converted to its boolean equivalent. Consult the [comparison table](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Comment: Use is_null() method inside `if` condition and it returns bool value